# Require jsx files without specifying extension

Tags: javascript, browserify, reactjs

I am using *browserify* and *watchify*, and would like to `require()` files other than the default extensions `.js` and `.json` without specifying the extension, for instance:

```
// Not ideal (tedious)
var Carousel = require('./components/Carousel/Carousel.jsx')

// Ideal
var Carousel = require('./components/Carousel/Carousel')
```

I have tried `--extension=EXTENSION` as specified in the *browserify* documentation:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "browserify ./src/App.js --transform [ reactify --es6 ] > dist/script.js -v -d --extension=jsx",
  "watch": "watchify ./src/App.js --transform [ reactify --es6 ] -o dist/script.js -v -d --extension=jsx"
},
```

However I don't see any change. Is this possible? What would be the right way to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Edit** (April 27, 2015):
I just noticed that in the question, I had an invalid argument for `extension`, like so:

```
"watch": "watchify ./src/App.js --extension=jsx -o dist/script.js -v -d"
```

It should be (notice the `.` (dot) in `--extension=.jsx`):

```
"watch": "watchify ./src/App.js --extension=.jsx -o dist/script.js -v -d"
```

**Original Answer**:

Adding in the `browserify` option to `package.json` did it for *browserify*  but not for *watchify*.

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "browserify ./src/App.js > dist/script.js -v -d",
  "watch": "watchify ./src/App.js -o dist/script.js -v -d"
},
"browserify": {
  "extension": [ "jsx" ],
  "transform": [ [ "reactify", { "es6": true } ] ]
}
```

Add in the `extension` option for the `watch` command made *watchify* work.

```
"watch": "watchify ./src/App.js --extension=.jsx -o dist/script.js -v -d"
```

However, non-DRY. I'd like to keep my commands short as possible, but ~oh well~.

Comment: For me browserify works only if I set the extension with `--extension=.jsx``

Comment: same as @amida.  extensions option seems to be totally broken via package.json or node api