# Unable to find module in npm

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Trying to run facebook flux app as mentioned [here](http://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/todo-list.html#content) . I have following tree structure for js application

```
│   .bundle.js
│   app.jsx
│   bundle.js
│
├───actions
│       TodoActions.jsx
│
├───components
│       Footer.jsx
│       Header.jsx
│       MainSection.jsx
│       TodoApp.jsx
│       TodoItem.jsx
│       TodoTextInput.jsx
│
├───constants
│       TodoConstants.jsx
│
├───dispatcher
│       AppDispatcher.jsx
│       Dispatcher.jsx
│
└───store
        TodoStore.jsx
```

In app.jsx code is like

```
 var React = require('react');
var TodoApp = require('./components/TodoApp');

    React.render(
      <TodoApp />,
      document.getElementById('todoapp')
    );
```

And in TodoApp.jsx I am exporting module as

```
module.exports = TodoApp;
```

When I am trying to make build.js it is making error as

```
Error: Cannot find module './components/TodoApp' from 'c:\www\example\react\flux\js'
```

Can't figure out where I am wrong ? Please let me know if I need to provide anything further on this

Answer (score 1):

After googling for some time I got the solution .Actual issue is `require`  looks for the `js` extension but I have files with `jsx` .

Got my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28159631/require-jsx-files-without-specifying-extension)

Comment: So the fix is `require('./components/TodoApp.jsx')`?