# How to specify browserify extensions in package.json?

Tags: javascript, browserify, package.json

In package.json:

```
...
"browserify": {
  "transform": [
    "coffee-reactify"
  ],
  "extension": [ ".cjsx", ".coffee", ".js", ".json" ],
  "extensions": [ ".cjsx", ".coffee", ".js", ".json" ]
},
...
```

When using browserify `transform` option works as expected, however browserify is not seeing `extension(s)` options - it throws error and I have to pass extension options manually to browserify...

---

in gulpfile.coffee

```
b = browserify
  entries: './' # ./ = root = directory where package.json is
  debug: true
b.bundle()
.pipe(source('client.js'))
.pipe(buffer())
.pipe(gulp.dest(distDir))
```

in package.json

```
"browser": "src/client/client",
"browserify": {
  "transform": [
    "coffee-reactify"
  ],
  "extension": [
    "cjsx",
    "coffee",
    "js",
    "json"
  ]
},
```

src/client/client.cjsx

```
otherModule = require './other-module' # other-module.cjsx
```

1. When I remove `coffee-reactify` from `transforms` in package.json then browserify throws error `Parsing file .../src/client/client.cjsx: Unexpected token (2:16)`
2. When I put back `coffee-reactify` to `transforms` in package.json, then browserify successfully parses `client.cjsx` as long as I wont require any other `.cjsx` files from inside of `client.cjsx`. So for the example code of `client.cjsx` above browserify throws error: `Cannot find module './other-module' from '/src/client` - browserify still does not recognize extension...

So browserify reads package.json (recognizes package.browserify.transforms and package.browser fields but it does not recognize extensions)

Comment: did you try to add, `--extension=[EXTENSION]` into your `browserify` command?

Comment: yes and it works, but I want it to work WITHOUT this option - I want to define it in my package.json instead...

Answer (score 1):

We were running into the same problem.  We were able to get it working by adding `extensions` to the `browserify` gulp function call.

```
browserify({
  entries: "src/index.coffee",
  extensions: [".cjsx", ".coffee", ".js", ".json" ]
})
```

We don't have it in the `package.json` at all, just in the gulp command.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"browserify": {
  "transform": [
    "coffee-reactify"
  ],
  "extension": [ 
    "cjsx", 
    "coffee", 
    "js", 
    "json" 
  ]
},
```

Remove the `.` dots. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28159631/require-jsx-files-without-specifying-extension).

Comment: how do your `package` scripts look like?

Comment: hmm. i searched for the "browserify" part in `package.json` but i did not found "extension". Just "transform" and some others.... Can you try to add the extensiond to your gulp task directly? like: `b = browserify
  entries: './' # ./ = root = directory where package.json is
  debug: true extension: [...]`

Comment: Yes I know it works like that - but I want browserify to use my package.json settings. I don't want to put "extensions" both inside package.json (for other users which will require my lib in browserify) and also inside gulpfile.coffee. I am not sure if its intensional behaviour of browserify or a bug. The fact is that browserify reads package.json but "sees" only browser/transform fields and not extension...

Comment: yes, i understand your problem. how i said, i think that there is no way to define `extensions` in `package.json`.At least from what i have found in the internet.